# Create list of user IDs for users not managed by terraform

Tags: terraform

I am configuring PagerDuty using terraform and part of that is assigning each user to a schedule.
In this scenario the users already exist in PagerDuty as they are pulled in from our SSO provider.

Initially this is how I looked at deploying the setup:
Use a data source to access the users details (such as ID)

`users.tf`

```
data "pagerduty_user" "user1" {
  email = "user1@test.com"
}

data "pagerduty_user" "user2" {
  email = "user2@test.co.nz"
}
```

Create and assign users to a schedule:

`schedule.tf`

```
resource "pagerduty_schedule" "schedule" {
  name      = "Rotation"
  time_zone = "Pacific/Auckland"

  layer {
    name                   = "On-Call"
    start                  = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    rotation_virtual_start = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    // One week rotation
    rotation_turn_length_seconds = 604800
    // The position of the user on the list determines their order in the layer.
    users = [data.pagerduty_user.user1.id, data.pagerduty_user.user2.id]
  }
  teams = [pagerduty_team.team.id]
}
```

This works correctly, however each time I wanted to add a new user to a team I would have to add duplicate blocks for each user.

My question is how can I avoid doing this?
My first thought was to use a `for_each`, so it would look like this:

`variables.tf`

```
variable "all_users" {
  description = "List of users"
  type        = map(any)
  default     = { user1 = "user1@test.com", user2 = "user1@test.com" }
}
```

`users.tf`

```
data "pagerduty_user" "users" {
  for_each = var.all_users
  email    = each.value
}
```

`schedule.tf`

```
resource "pagerduty_schedule" "schedule" {
  for_each  = data.pagerduty_user.users
  name      = "Rotation"
  time_zone = "Pacific/Auckland"

  layer {
    name                   = "On-Call"
    start                  = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    rotation_virtual_start = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    // One week rotation
    rotation_turn_length_seconds = 604800
    // The position of the user on the list determines their order in the layer.
    users = [data.pagerduty_user.users[each.key].id]
  }
  teams = [pagerduty_team.team.id]
}
```

The issue here is that two schedules are being created (which would is the expected behavior).
So, my question is how can I create a list of User IDs what I could then pass to the schedule?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this with locals:

```
locals {
  users = [
    for user in data.pagerduty_user.users :
    user.id
  ]
}
```

So my final config ended up as:

`variables.tf`

```
variable "all_users" {
  description = "List of storage users"
  type        = list(any)
  default     = ["user1", "user2"]
}
```

`users.tf`

```
data "pagerduty_user" "users" {
  for_each = toset(var.all_users)
  email    = "${each.value}@test.com"
}
```

`schedules.tf`

```
locals {
  users = [
    for user in data.pagerduty_user.users :
    user.id
  ]
}

resource "pagerduty_schedule" "storage_schedule" {
  name      = "Storage Team Rotation"
  time_zone = "Pacific/Auckland"

  layer {
    name                   = "On-Call"
    start                  = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    rotation_virtual_start = "2021-09-10T00:00:00-00:00"
    // One week rotation
    rotation_turn_length_seconds = 604800
    // The position of the user on the list determines their order in the layer.
    users = local.users
  }
  teams = [pagerduty_team.storage.id]
}
```